# Searching a list to see if there is a match python

Tags: python, list, class

Basically this is within a class which appends objects of another class to list self. There are 200 objects in list self. So basically if I call self[1] I will get ['John',['Alex', 'Rob']. Basically 'john' refers to self.firstname and the other names refer to there group members. For example the below will print the firstnames and groupmembers of each object for all 200 objects

```
  for line in self:
    print line.firstname

for line in self:
print line.groupmembers
```

Now I have to create something that goes through all the names and checks the names. So basically if John has Alex and Rob as members then there has to be another object with a first name Alex and another object with a firstname Rob. So say there is no object with firstname Alex I want to print 'mismatch'. This is what I have so far but its not doing what its intended to do.

```
    def name(self):
            firstnames = []
            for item in self:
                firstnames.append(item.firstname)
            for item1 in self:
                for i in item1.groupmembers:
                    if i not in hello:
                        print 'mismatch'
```

Comment: What is `for item in self` supposed to do? Does your class subclass something iterable or otherwise correctly implement the behavior?

Comment: each item in self (this has 200 objects) is a different student object. So I am going through each object and appending there first name to a list

Comment: Does your class subclass something iterable or otherwise correctly implement this behavior? You can't pass just any class's instance through a `for` loop and have it work.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so first off, `line` and `self` are bad variable names.
`self` should only be used within a class to be used as a way to call or use its own variables.

Secondly, you say each value in this self list contains values like `['John',['Alex', 'Rob']`, but then you go on to use it like a class object... and frankly that don't do make none sense.

So to remedy this, I'm going to assume its done with class objects. I would also rename self to something like school, and instead of calling an element of self; line, which yields no information to the reader.. call it a student!

I'm going to assume your class would start looking like this:

```
class Student:
    # having an empty default value makes it easy to see what types variables should be!
    firstname = ""
    groupmembers = []
    def __init__(self,firstname,groupmembers ):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.groupmembers = groupmembers
```

Then if you have a list of people you can loop through them like so..

```
>>>school = [Student("foo", ["bar", "that guy"]),
          Student("bar", ["foo", "that guy"])]

>>>for student in school:
    print student.firstname
    print student.groupmembers

foo 
["bar", "that guy"]
bar
["foo", "that guy"]
```

Then to check it a students group members are in school you can add a function to the Student class

```
class Student:
    # having an empty default value makes it easy to see what types variables should be!
    firstname = ""
    groupmembers = []
    def __init__(self,firstname,groupmembers ):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.groupmembers = groupmembers

    def group_present(self, school):
        # This is how you would get all the names of kids in school without list comprehension
        attendance = []
        for student in school:
            attendance.append(student.firstname)
        # this is with list comprehension
        attendance = [ student.firstname for student in school]
        #compare group members with attendance
        #note that I write student_name, not student
        ## helps point out that it is a string not a class
        for student_name in self.groupmembers:
            if not student_name in attendance:
                print "Group member '{}' is missing :o!! GASP!".format(student_name)
```

In idle:

```
>>> school[0].group_present(school)
Group member 'that guy' is missing :o!! GASP!
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand exactly but maybe you can use **contains**

```
self[1].__contains__('Alex')
```

this should return true in case of existence or false otherwise.

Comment: Did you mean `"Alex" in self[1]`?